# Booting a Linux kernel ARM64 boot executable Image

Tags: linux, qemu, arm64

I am self learning reverse engineering and working on reversing a firmware image for an unknown ioT device that's running on Zephyr. I have the firmware image (.img file), which returns '*Linux kernel ARM64 boot executable Image*' when running the *file* command. I've tried running *binwalk* to extract anything meaningful, but all I get is the Linux kernel ARM64 image and text. My question is, is it even possible to boot this image and how can I go about this?

Comment: Maybe possible depending on the model: https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/boards/arm64/index.html